# how to make WCF service use a specific DataContractSerializer constructor overload?

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

DataContractSerializer has many [constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.DATACONTRACTSERIALIZER.#CTOR%22%29;k%28DATACONTRACTSERIALIZER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), and I'd like to be able to specify how my WCF service should initialize the DataContractSerializer it uses. How would you go about doing this? Is it easier to configure this in the .config file or in C#?

A WCF service always appears to use [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404901.aspx) by default.

If possible, please give an example of how to specify [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx) for KnownTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. See

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.85).aspx

for guidance. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f30ecd17-cac0-4cdc-8142-90b5f411936b/) shows how to swap the serializer in WCF with another. You could create your own wrapper with the constructor that you want and swap it in.

Comment: Thanks, although  I think I have to edit my question to be more specific on what I'm asking.